# How to vibrate on android oreo

Tags: android, cordova, android-8.0-oreo, vibration

I'm searching since 3 weeks and I'm going crazy! I have try every code I seen on each forum but i'm not able to have vibration on my android app on android 8.0, I have made an app with cordova, i have try to make a plugin with (vibrator) (vibrationeffect) nothing, i have try to make a blank native app with android studio, nothing. It work only on lower version of Android.

Vibration is essential for my app and I try it on 2 phone with Android 8 and I have the same problem, logcat say everythings ok, navigator.vibrate don't work because vibrate is not on touch (it's a little game).

I need your help please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Initialize the Vibrator class:

```
 Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) Context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

2.) Call vibrate

```
 vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(30, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have this code and I just found the problem, on the 2 phone there as a battery saving mode whitch disable vibration, is it possible to detect if vibration is available (hasVibrator always say true), i found something to change system setting but I just want to say for the user that vibration is disable because of battery saving mode and the user will be able to disable this mode by himself.