# Android don't vibrate for values less than 5000 milliseconds

Tags: java, android, vibration

I'm trying to make vibrate in Android, this is my (typical) vibration code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    vb.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(300, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
} else {
    //deprecated in API 26
    vb.vibrate(300);
}
```

My problem is that if I use less than 5000 milliseconds as the first parameter (300 in the example), the phone doesn't vibrate but if I use >= 5000 milliseconds works.

Note: in Android devices with < SDK26 version works > SDK26 no...

Idea? Thanks

Comment: Check if the device has some kind of battery saving mode which might be disabled the vibration ...I got this from a comment to an answer here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553799/9365212

Comment: I don't have saving mode battery activated and I have tried activating and deactivating the battery manager.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue turns out the user has to enable Touch vibration in Settings